# How to highlight a DBGrid cell?

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to programatically highlight the current cell in a TDBGrid descendant.   If I do DBGrid.SetFocus, I get the combo box arrow below, which isn't sufficiently highlighted for me.

EDIT:

I'm already doing DBGrid.SelectedField := DataSource.FieldByName('Name');

To bring the user's attention more to the region in question, I set:

```
DBGrid.Columns[x].Title.Font.Style := [fsbold, fsunderline];
```

And I set a timer that after five seconds does:

```
DBGrid.Columns[x].Title.Font.Style := [];
```

What's weird is that after the time goes off, the cell becomes blue (as shown below.) *That's the highlight I wanted in the first place.* But I don't know enough about grids to know how to get that directly.

My question: how to I get a grid cell highlighted as in the blue example below?  I've never done anything like this before, so I'm a bit lost.  Is this an InPlaceEditor function?

I'm using a descendant of TDBGrid, so I'm not sure if the behavior I'm seeing is intrinsic to TDBGrid, or just in the descendant (in which case I know my question can't be answered here.  )

[image: Two controls]

Comment: Doesn't `SelectedField` property do what you need?

Comment: @iManBiglari Yes, I was already doing that, but forgot to note it. I've edited the original post.  The problem remains.

Comment: OK. How about a call to either `Invalidate()` or `Repaint()` after settings `SelectedField`?

Comment: I'm also interested in the answer of the question painted on the image. What's the difference between the two states?

Comment: @iManBiglari Adding Invalidate and Repaint don't help.  I don't know what the difference is between the two states in the image either! Thanks, by the way, for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using the following (D2007) using the `DBGrid: OnDrawColumnCell` event.

```
procedure TForm1.DBGridDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin 
  //Make the column blue if the title is bold
  if (fsBold in Column.Title.Font.Style) then
    TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Brush.Color := $00fff0e1;

  //Set the selected row to white/bold text on blue background
  if (gdSelected in State) then
    begin
      TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Brush.Color := clHighlight;
      TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Font.Style := Font.Style + [fsBold];
      TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Font.Color := clHighlightText;
    end;

  //Update the grid
  TDBGrid(Sender).DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
end;
```

Comment: That should work, Pieter. Thanks, but I'm hoping that somehow I can toggle the grid cell into a state that causes the highlighting, as is happening by some unknown method today.